# how to get the current values of an input on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, closest

I have a bunch of div's that have the same functionality and I'm trying to write a function for them.

Basically they have a predetermined value and a user input value and those need to be multiplied.

I've looked through a bunch of other questions and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465955/get-the-value-of-this-input-box-with-jquery) is the closest one I could find.  Almost exactly, but none of those answers work.

Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance!

```
<div>
   <label>enter value for multiple here</label>
   <input type="text" class="multiple" factor="foo1"/>
   <button type="button" class="multiplyBtn">Click here to multiply these numbers</button>

   <label>enter value for multiple here</label>
   <input type="text" class="multiple" factor="foo2"/>
   <button type="button" class="multiplyBtn">Click here to multiply these numbers</button>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$('.mulitplyBtn').click(function() {
   var factor = $(this).closest('attr.factor').val();
   var multiple = $(this)closest('.multiple').val();
   answer = (factor * multiple);
};
```

Comment: 1. Your javascript has unmatched quotes. `"` and `'` are different. 2. Where is your `.factor`? It would help to provide it in order to understand what you are trying to do. 3. `$(this)closest(.multiple).val()` should be `$(this)closest('.multiple').val()`

Comment: Is `factor="foo1"` the value you want to multiply by?

Comment: @Caner, the '.factor' is an attribute at then end of the input.  They are predetermined and need to be multiplied by the user input to get the answer.  Does that explain it better?  Let me know if I can clarify it better for you.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```js
$('.multiplyBtn').click(function() { // you had multiplyBtn spelled wrong here
  var cur = $('.multiplyBtn').index($(this)); // get index of clicked btn
  var factor = $('.multiple').eq(cur).data('factor'); // get factor from matching input
  var multiple = $('.multiple').eq(cur).val(); // get value from matching input
  answer = (Number(factor) * Number(multiple)); // make sure both are numbers then multiply
  alert(answer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>enter value for multiple here</label>
  <input type="text" class="multiple" data-factor="4" />
  <button type="button" class="multiplyBtn">Click here to multiply these numbers</button>
  <br>

  <label>enter value for multiple here</label>
  <input type="text" class="multiple" data-factor="7" />
  <button type="button" class="multiplyBtn">Click here to multiply these numbers</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this did it.  Thanks so much.  Been banging my head against the wall all morning.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you used " and ' try using the same quotes (I mean using ".multiplyBtn" or '.multiplyBtn' )

Second time, 3rd line you didn't use any quote when calling .multiple. So turn it in that format : var multiple = $(this)closest('.multiple').val()

let me know the result

Comment: They still come up undefined

Answer (score 0):

`attr.factor` does not work like this.

try it like this:

```
$('.multiplyBtn').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).prev('.multiple'); //don't forget the "dot"
    var multiple = container.val();
    var factor = container.attr('factor'); //since it is the same container. 
    var answer = (factor * multiple); //what exactly are you tryin to multiply?
};
```

Comment: I tried using it this way and the variables come up as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two typos and are using the wrong jQuery function.

Typos:

- $('.mulitplyBtn') should be $('.mulitplyBtn')
- $(this)closest should be $(this).closest

Wrong function:

closest() searches the parents, and the only parent here is the DIV with no class.  What you probably want is to use parent() to go up to the DIV, then find() to search the parent's children for a specific element:

```
$(this).parent().find('.multiple').val()
```

Comment: This worked for the multiple variable, but the factor still comes up undefined.